# how to prevent Python garbage collection for anonymous objects?

Tags: python, garbage-collection

In this Python code

```
import gc
gc.disable()
<some code ...>
MyClass()
<more code...>
```

I am hoping that the anonymous object created by `MyClass` constructor would not be garbage-collected.  `MyClass` actually links to a shared object library of C++ code, and there through raw memory pointers I am able to inspect the contents of the anonymous object.

I can then see that the object is immediately corrupted (garbage collected).

How to prevent Python garbage collection for everything?

I have to keep this call anonymous.  I cannot change the part of the code `MyClass()` - it has to be kept as is.

`MyClass()` has to be kept as is, because it is an exact translation from C++ (by way of SWIG) and the two should be identical for the benefit of people who translate.

I have to prevent the garbage collection by some "initialization code", that is only called once at the beginning of the program.  I cannot touch anything after that.

Comment: Why don't you just assign it to something?  That seems like a simpler solution than fiddling with gc details.

Comment: @BrenBarn I know.  I specifically do not want to assign, but keep it anonymous.

Comment: @MarkGaleck: Why can't you assign it?  Will something bad happen if you do, or are you searching for only the most convoluted solution to your self-imposed problem?

Comment: @MarkGaleck: But why?  It seems like the only thing you "lose" by not assigning it is a solution to your problem.

Comment: @jwodder Because the call `MyClass()` is translated from C++ (by way of SWIG) and in C++ it is anonymous, and the two have to be kept exactly the same, for the benefit of the people who translate them.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me, and I'm not sure what the real problem being solved is.  This means that it's not clear what workarounds would be acceptable.

Comment: @DSM like I said, the acceptable solution, would be for me to put something before the call to `MyClass()`, which would prevent the garbage collection of the anonymous object.

Comment: Okay, so add `_anonymous_object =\\` to the line before.  Your need to have the object be anonymous makes little sense in Python, and I don't follow the SWIG-related constraints.

Comment: @DSM fair enough, let me clarify

Comment: do you intend for this to be portable to implementations other than cpython? aside from adding the instance to a GC root, no garbage collector tricks are going to work in those other implementations.  pypy in particular, where cpyext extensions work well, has a fast evolving garbage collector, no tricks work for long.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "garbage collector" referred to in `gc` is only used for resolving circular references. In Python (at least in the main C implementation, CPython) the main method of memory management is reference counting. In your code, the result of `MyClass()` has no references, so will always be disposed immediately. There's no way of preventing that.

What is not clear, even with your edit, is why you can't simply assign it to something? If the target audience is "people who translate", those people can presumably read, so write a comment explaining why you're doing the assignment.

Comment: I am not translating myself, they are translating.  And it has to be made as easy as possible for them.  Your answer is good because it explains to me, that there is no way to accomplish that.  So "they" will have to translate it with assignment.

Comment: @MarkGaleck, you could change your `MyClass()` constructor to save a reference to `self`. Where? Anywhere. Say, append `self` to some module-global list hidden in the module. Then it would be invisible to users.